# "Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary."

Tags: apache-spark, tensorflow, pyspark, databricks

I am following the databricks tutorial on their community edition:

https://docs.databricks.com/applications/deep-learning/deep-learning-pipelines.html#install-deep-learning-pipelines

attached libraries:

> spark-deep-learning, tensorflow, keras, h5py, tensorframes

when running this cell:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from sparkdl import DeepImageFeaturizer

featurizer = DeepImageFeaturizer(inputCol="image", outputCol="features", modelName="InceptionV3")
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=20, regParam=0.05, elasticNetParam=0.3, labelCol="label")
p = Pipeline(stages=[featurizer, lr])

p_model = p.fit(train_df)
```

I am getting this Error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: u'NodeDef mentions attr \'dilations\' not in Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_FLOAT]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID"]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]>; NodeDef: given/conv2d_95/convolution = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](given/sub_1, given/conv2d_95/kernel/read). (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).'
```

*I am stuck please help me out :)

Comment: Hello @Dipak, I am facing the same issue but with faster_rcnn_resnet101_kitti from Tensorflow model zoo. Do you have the same issue with this model? For more detail, please refer tohttps://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4093. Thank you for precious time on my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is downgrading your tensorflow to 1.4.0

Answer (score 2):

I got it working with tensorflow 1.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes across this issue then doing pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu and installing it again worked for me. Most likely a version issue. Im on 1.14 now.

Comment: This worked for me! I did `conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.14` , for those who need!