# Error "Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary." when running TFLite model in Android

Tags: python, android, firebase, tensorflow, tflite

I built a **keras-ocr tflite** model using [ocr_tflite](https://github.com/tulasiram58827/ocr_tflite).

Following are the tensorflow library versions used on mac osx m1 -

```
tensorflow-datasets       4.8.3
tensorflow-deps           2.10.0
tensorflow-estimator      2.9.0
tensorflow-macos          2.9.0
tensorflow-metadata       1.12.0
tensorflow-metal          0.5.0
```

. The model has the following shapes -

```
input - [  1  31 200   1]
<class 'numpy.float32'>
output - [ 1 48]
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

I hosted this model on firebase and tried using it in my android app using below code -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final File[] modelFile = new File[1];
    final Interpreter[] interpreter = new Interpreter[1];
    Interpreter.Options options = new Interpreter.Options();

    FirebaseCustomRemoteModel remoteModel = new FirebaseCustomRemoteModel.Builder("ocr-float16-3-8").build();
    FirebaseModelDownloadConditions conditions = new FirebaseModelDownloadConditions.Builder().build();
    FirebaseModelManager.getInstance()
            .download(remoteModel, conditions)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "downloading model");
                    FirebaseModelManager.getInstance().getLatestModelFile(remoteModel).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<File>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<File> task) {
                            modelFile[0] = task.getResult();
                            interpreter[0] = new Interpreter(modelFile[0], options);
                            Log.d("TAG", "built local model");
                            predict(interpreter[0]);
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "failure " + e);
                }
            });
}

private void predict(Interpreter interpreter) {
        Bitmap grayedBitmap;
        Bitmap inputBitmap = null;
        try {
            inputBitmap = getBitmapFromAssets("word_4.png"); // not included in the question
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inputBitmap, 200, 31, true);
        grayedBitmap = toGrayScale(inputBitmap); // not included in the question
        Log.d("TAG", "created grayed bitmap");
        ByteBuffer input = getByteBuffer(grayedBitmap); // not included in the question
        Log.d("TAG", "converted grayed bitmap");
        int bufferSize = 48 * java.lang.Integer.SIZE / java.lang.Byte.SIZE;
        ByteBuffer modelOutput = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bufferSize).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        interpreter.run(input, modelOutput);
        modelOutput.rewind();
        IntBuffer probabilities = modelOutput.asIntBuffer();
        StringBuilder predicted = new StringBuilder();
        String []alphabetIndex = new String[]{"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
        for(int i=0; i<48; i++) {
            int prob = probabilities.get(i);
            if(prob != -1 && prob != 36) {
                predicted.append(alphabetIndex[prob]);
            }
        }
        Log.d("TAG", "predicted string is " + predicted.toString());
    }
```

But I get error -

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: games.cloudfeather.mlkitcustom2, PID: 16074
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Failed to run on the given Interpreter: NodeDef mentions attr 'blank_index' not in Op<name=CTCGreedyDecoder; signature=inputs:T, sequence_length:int32 -> decoded_indices:int64, decoded_values:int64, decoded_shape:int64, log_probability:T; attr=merge_repeated:bool,default=false; attr=T:type,default=DT_FLOAT,allowed=[DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE]>; NodeDef: {{node CTCGreedyDecoder}}. (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).
         (while executi
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(Native Method)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:163)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:360)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:319)
        at games.cloudfeather.mlkitcustom2.MainActivity.predict(MainActivity.java:115)
        at games.cloudfeather.mlkitcustom2.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:39)
        at games.cloudfeather.mlkitcustom2.MainActivity$2$1.onComplete(MainActivity.java:63)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

on line `interpreter.run(input, modelOutput);`

I have following lines added to my **build.gradle** file (app level) -

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:22.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-modeldownloader'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.4.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.1.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.3.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:2.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

I have looked into other Stackoverflow questions with same title like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723686/check-whether-your-graphdef-interpreting-binary-is-up-to-date-with-your-graphde) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56210011/fix-for-check-weather-your-graph-def-interpreting-binary-is-up-to-date-with-you) where people have solved it by downgrading tensorflow but I don't know upto which version I should downgrade to.

Also when I use prebuilt **keras-ocr tflite** models from the [repo](https://github.com/tulasiram58827/ocr_tflite/tree/main/models) itself, everything works fine.

Question: Which version can I use so that I can run my model in my app successfully?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by converting *.h5* into *.tflite* using **tensorflow 2.4**

Conversion using later versions is not working.